# How to accept on session payments with saved cards using Stripe's PaymentIntents API

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am working on Stripe's React Native SDK to accept payments on my App. It's working perfectly when I am trying to add a card and pay. In the process I am adding `setup_future_usage` to save the card (payment method) for future usage. But I am not sure how to charge the saved card in future.

In the Stripe docs, they have mentioned about off-session payments and the recovery flow in case the off session payment fails because it requires authentication but I could not find any information about on-session payments with saved cards.

I have the `PaymentMethodId` and `Client Secret` (from the PaymentIntent) but I am not sure how to confirm the payment.

Answer (score 0):

PaymentMethods objects are designed for one-time usage unless attached to a customer.

In this particular case, you'll need to attach the PaymentMethod created from your PaymentIntent to a pre-existing (or new customer). You can then pass the `pm_xxx` ID to `confirmCardPayment`.